# Qt4 Stylesheet Pseudo-states

Tags: qt4, stylesheet

I'm attempting to change the style of a button using the :checked and :unchecked pseudo-states, but have not been successful.

I have tried a variety of different combinations to no avail.

```
#btnOnOff:checked { ... }
#btnOnOff:unchecked { ... }
#btnOnOff.QPushButton:unchecked { ... }
```

None of these seem to be working.

Comment: Can you post some code and your stylesheet contents related to #btnOnOff? How do you set the stylesheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
QPushButton#btnOnOff:checked {}
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried that and it also does not seem to work for me.